# Java generics type mismatch in method signature

Tags: java, generics

I have an `Executor` class that invokes instances of interface `IService<T>` with `KeyList<T>` argument.

```
   class Executor{
      KeyList<?> _keys;
      IService<?> _service;
      public Executor(IService<?> service, KeyList<?> keys){
         _service = service;
         _keys = keys;
      }

      public void execute(){
         _service.invoke(_keys);
      }
   }

   interface IService<T>{
      public void invoke( KeyList<T> keys);
   }

   class KeyList<T> {
      List<T> _list;
   }
```

I used `<?>` for the Executor's members since it does not care how IService and KeyList are parameterized, but the following raises a compilation error saying the arguments are not applicable:

```
 public void execute(){
    _service.invoke(_keys); //error on invoke
 }
```

I'm guessing it's complaining becuase `KeyList<?>` is not equal to `KeyList<T>`, but `<?>` is the same as `<? extends Object>`, so I'm a bit confused. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 3):

A [wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) (`?`) represents some specific unknown type. But you're dealing with two separate wildcards here - they may not be the same. Use the following instead:

```
class Executor<T> {
    KeyList<T> _keys;
    IService<T> _service;
    public Executor(IService<T> service, KeyList<T> keys){
        _service = service;
        _keys = keys;
    }

    public void execute(){
        _service.invoke(_keys);
    }
}
```

This declares a type parameter `T` for the class `Executor`, and then uses it as a type argument for `_keys` and `_service`, ensuring they're compatible.

If you can't parameterize `Executor`, try using a parameterized helper class:

```
class Executor {

    private static final class ServiceAndKeys<T> {

        private final KeyList<T> keys;
        private final IService<T> service;

        ServiceAndKeys(IService<T> service, KeyList<T> keys) {
            this.service = service;
            this.keys = keys;
        }

        void execute() {
            service.invoke(keys);
        }
    }

    private final ServiceAndKeys<?> serviceAndKeys;

    public <T> Executor(IService<T> service, KeyList<T> keys){
        serviceAndKeys = new ServiceAndKeys<T>(service, keys);
    }

    public void execute() {
        serviceAndKeys.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you eventually assign

```
IService<?> _service;
```

it will have some type. Consider this a `type-1`.

When you eventually assign

```
KeyList<?> _keys;
```

it will have some type. Consider this a `type-2`.

Nothing says that these types are compatible and therefore the compiler doesn't allow it. This has to do with [Capture Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10).

> If Ti is a wildcard type argument (§4.5.1) of the form ?, then Si is a
>   fresh type variable whose upper bound is Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn] and
>   whose lower bound is the null type (§4.1).

Therefore each `<?>` is a different type variable.

An ugly solution is to simply remove the wildcard type declaration altogether

```
KeyList _keys;
IService _service;
```

but you may run into other troubles at runtime.

Comment: The raw type will work, but just thinking about it gives me hives :-D, thx