# How to avoid creating specific implementations for Generic types

Tags: java, generics

This is an example program am trying.

I am dealing with Items - Single or Multi

```
public interface IItem<T> { 
    T getContents();    
}

/** An item that holds a Map and uses it for something  */
public class SingleItem implements IItem<Map<String,String>> {
    . . . . .
}

/** An item that holds a List of maps and uses it for something  */
public class MultiItem implements IItem<List<Map<String,String>>> {
    . . . . .
}
```

Producers that can produce SingleItems or MultiItems

```
public interface IProducer<T> { 
    T produce();
}

public class SingleItemProducer implements IProducer<SingleItem> {

    @Override
    public SingleItem produce() {
        return new SingleItem(...);
    }
}

public class MultiItemProducer implements IProducer<MultiItem> {
    . . . . . 
    . . . . .
}
```

Consumers that can consume SingleItems or MultiItems

```
public interface IConsumer<T> {
    void consume(T item);
}

public class SingleItemConsumer implements IConsumer<SingleItem> {

    @Override
    public void consume(SingleItem item) {  
        System.out.println(item.getContents());
    }
}

public class MultiItemConsumer implements IConsumer<MultiItem> {
    . . . . .
    . . . . .     
}
```

Processors that will use Producers & Consumers to get the work done.

```
public interface IProcessor<T> {
    void process();
    void process(T item);
}

/** A generic processor that should be able to work with any type of consumer or producer */
public class GenericItemProcessor implements IProcessor<IItem<? extends Object>> {

    IProducer<IItem<? extends Object>> producer;
    IConsumer<IItem<? extends Object>> consumer;

    public GenericItemProcessor (IProducer<IItem<? extends Object>> p, IConsumer<IItem<? extends Object>> c) {
        this.producer = p;
        this.consumer = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void process() {
        IItem<? extends Object> item = null;
        // As long the producer produces items, keep processing them
        while ((item = producer.produce()) != null) {
            this.process(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void process(IItem<? extends Object> item) {
        consumer.consume(item);
    }
}
```

And, in the main program, when I try this,

```
IProducer<SingleItem> producer = new SingleItemProducer();
IConsumer<SingleItem> consumer= new SingleItemConsumer();
IProcessor<IItem<? extends Object>> processor = new GenericItemProcessor(producer, consumer);
```

It says I can't do the last assignment.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor GenericItemProcessor(IProducer<SingleItem>, IConsumer<SingleItem>) is undefined
```

Of course, this would work,

```
IProcessor<SingleItem> processor = new GenericItemProcessor(producer, consumer);
```

If I replace all occurances of `IItem<? extends Object>` with `SingleItem` inside `GenericItemProcessor`.

But the problem with that is that I have to create a processor to process each item type, which looks like it would defeat the purpose of having a Generic 'Typed' processor.

May be am missing something obvious here, but, how can this be done correctly ? Would appreciate some advice.

Comment: In Scala, this would be done with contravariant and covariant type parameters for Consumer and Producer - but sorry, I don't know how to translate that into Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java generics type mismatch in method signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749005/java-generics-type-mismatch-in-method-signature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of generics in `GenericItemProcessor` is too complex I think. The code in the processor does not take usage of the fact, that the processor produces `IItem` objects, so its not necessary to bind the generic type to `IItem<? extends Object>`:

```
/** A generic processor that should be able to work with any type of consumer or producer */
public class GenericProcessor<T> implements IProcessor<T> {

    IProducer<? extends T> producer;
    IConsumer<? super T> consumer;

    public GenericProcessor(IProducer<? extends T> p, IConsumer<? super T> c) {
        this.producer = p;
        this.consumer = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void process() {
        T item = null;
        // As long the producer produces items, keep processing them
        while ((item = producer.produce()) != null) {
            this.process(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void process(T item) {
        consumer.consume(item);
    }
}
```

So this code is no problem now:

```
IProducer<SingleItem> producer = new SingleItemProducer();
IConsumer<SingleItem> consumer = new SingleItemConsumer();
IProcessor<SingleItem> processor = new GenericProcessor<SingleItem>(
    producer, consumer);
```

Apart from that, this will make your processor even more generic as it now can handle any producer/consumer even if they do not produce/consume `IItem` objects. Note the usage of `? extends T` for the producer and `? super T` for the consumer. Due to that, you can 'connect' every producer, that produces instances of subclasses of a certain type to consumers that accept instances of a super class of that same type:

```
IProducer<Integer> producer = new IntegerProducer();
IConsumer<Object> consumer = new ObjectConsumer();
IProcessor<Number> processor = new GenericProcessor<Number>(
    producer, consumer);
```