# Java: Is it possible to say a variable type must meet multiple inheritence/interface requirements

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

In some code I am working with I have an existing third party API that implements things extending from A (and perhaps not directly, but via X, and perhaps also implementing a bunch of other interfaces).

Now for the code I am working on, I have an interface IB, that provides additional capabilities to what A offers. As such a lot of my code actually has the requirement that the object passed to it extends A, and also implements IB, but there is no way to declare that for my member variables I can think of. But picking either A or IB results in a lot of casts.

I guess if A was/had an interface IA would solve this, but there is no way I can change A, or for my implementations of IB to not need to extend A (the third party code uses A, and takes care of a lot of management, persistence, networking, user interfacing, etc. via it).

```
class Z {
    private List<?what here?> items;
    /**The implementer of IB should know how to find the Z instance and call this.*/
    private void subscribe(? item) {
        items.add(item);
    }
    public void doSomethingWithItems() {
        ...code thats requires facilities from A and IB...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generic helper class, whose type parameter lets you use a type intersection:

```
class Z {

    private static final class Wrapper<T extends A & IB> {

        private final T item;

        Wrapper(final T item) {
            this.item = item;
        }

        void doWork() {
            // code thats requires facilities from A and IB
        }
    }

    private List<Wrapper<?>> wrappers;

    private <T extends A & IB> void subscribe(T item) {
        wrappers.add(new Wrapper<T>(item));
    }
    public void doSomethingWithItems() {
        for (final Wrapper<?> wrapper : wrappers) {
            wrapper.doWork();
        }
    }
```

I gave a similar answer on this post: [Java generics type mismatch in method signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749005/java-generics-type-mismatch-in-method-signature)

Comment: "List<Item<?>>" being "List<Wrapper<?>>" I assume? Going to try this, hadnt really considered making the method generic as well.

Comment: @FireLancer Yeah, corrected. I went back and forth about what to name it :)

Comment: That's a really neat trick to bootstrap first class intersection types from the intersection types for type parameters Java offers. I will be adding that to my toolbox for ugly generics problems :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a type *intersection*:

```
<T extends A & IB>
```

The rules are that if one of the types is a class, it must be listed first.

I would type the class if you can:

```
class Z<T extends A & IB> {
    private List<T> items;

    private void subscribe(T item) {
        items.add(item);
    }
    public void doSomethingWithItems() {
        // the items are both A and IB
    }
}
```

If you can't type Z, go for typed methods:

```
class Z {
    private List<A>items;

    private <T extends A & IB> void subscribe(T item) {
        items.add(item);
    }
    public void doSomethingWithItems() {
        // items are A, but if you want IB functionality you must cast.
        // the cast is safe if items are only added via subscribe()
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is T? The Z instance is used for anything that meets the requirements, not a specific type of thing, so the same z instance can be given Abc or Xyz objects that are unrelated except for extending A and implementing IB.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9 "It is not possible to write an intersection type directly as part of a program; no syntax supports this. " I guess is what this is?

Comment: @fire huh? This compiles. What's the problem?

Comment: @paul it should compile. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Bohemian I was referring to your initial answer of `List<? extends A & IB>`. Now I think the issue is that the OP doesn't want to parameterize `Z` with a specific type, but have it maintain a heterogenous list of objects that subtype `A` and `IB`.

Comment: @PaulBellora hmmm I wondered that too, but I'm reasonably sure it's intersection he wants, not an OR of types.

Answer (score 2):

It would be most ideomatic if IB were a subtype of IA, but if you can't do that ...

It is difficult to express this in code, as Java does not support first class intersection types. That is, Java only supports intersection types in bounds of type parameters, and we can't use a type parameter in the field declaration without requiring that all elements of the list are of the same subtype of IB.

Therefore, the best approximation I can think of is to enforce the constraint only in the public API, and use casts internally:

```
class Z {
    private List<A> items;

    private <B extends A & IB> void subscribe(B item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public void doSomethingWithItems() {
        for (A a : items) {
            IB b = (IB) a; // safe because we checked it on subscription
            // use features of A and IB
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, it is ugly. That's why newer JVM languages such a Ceylon feature first class intersection types. That is, in Ceylon, one could simply write:

```
class Z() {

    List<A & IB> items;

    void subscribe(A & IB item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    void doSomethingWithItems() {
        for (item in items) {
            // use features of A and IB
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a new abstract class, that both implements IB with abstract methods, and extends A.  Then you could make all the classes that you need to use extend your new abstract class.

Comment: What does IC do then? An abstract class there is fine as long as nothing else in the entire system with any form of overlap ever does that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Are you proposing that there are two different interfaces `IB` and `IC`, and I'll need some classes that extend `A` and implement `IB`; some more classes that extend `A` and implement `IC`; and still more that extend `A` and implement both `IB` and `IC`?  Is that your question, or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes, potentially, which lands in the no multiple-inheritence problem . Also some implementations of IB might already have a different base, say AExtended. Was the entire reason IB is an interface to start with

Comment: OK, fair call.  If you're likely to have stuff like that, then it may be better to try Bohemian's solution.  I think mine might make more sense in the simpler cases, but I agree that it doesn't cover every possibility.